# Array is re-initialized every time

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to add the values to list as show in below code. i am getting error.

if i use like below

```
for (String n2 : number  ) {
List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
 Email(n2);
  ARRAY.add(n2);
 }
 }
```

if i am using above. Though already email sent with value n2 again it is sending again. For first it has to sent but for second time n2 should be in array but still it sending. any one help. if n2 is passed to email second time it should not pass.

I am re-posting question as pervious one seems not clear i guess.

Comment: `ARRAY`s declaration is inside the loop, why do you think it's reinitialized every time?

Comment: It's better to edit your previous unclear question than posting new one here

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `ARRAY` outside of the for loop

```
List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();   // maybe as a class field
for (String n2 : number  ) {

  if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
     Email(n2);
     ARRAY.add(n2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Though i moved out side of the for loop. Since these in thread which runs very 5 mins. Array is getting re-initialised. mail is sent .. is there any way where we avoid that

Comment: as per my comment, maybe make the ARRAY a class field so that it does not get recreated

Comment: when i execute with above mail sent with same number every 5 mins as it runs :(

Comment: so move it to your calling code, not inside the Thread.  or move it to some other singleton code.

Comment: but every 5 mins it has to check the numbers if any newnumbers than mail has to sent.. so only it is kept inside the thread

Comment: your comment does not make sense.  Think about visibility and scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This line needs to be outside of your loop.

**Why?**

Simple. It's an issue of [scope](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm). Scope is the the lifetime and accessibility of a variable. In this case, you declare it inside of a `loop`, so the scope of that variable is, you guessed it, the loop. When the loop exits, the variable is destroyed.

You need to move it outside, so that the variable persists for the lifetime of the loop.

**Extra Reading**

Please, read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java).